# What is the fastest way to convert JPEG byte data to raw greyscale byte information?

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg, grayscale

Since the Raw callback from takePhoto is not reliable I have to use the JPEG callback... What I'm basicly getting is a byte array which holds all the information in JPEG data-form. I now need to somehow get this to be only grayscale information with each pixel having a value of 0-255...

At the moment I'm converting the jpeg data array to Bitmap using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray and then converting the bitmap to grayscale by using getPixel(), which is pretty bad performance wise...

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What about a greyscale ColorMatrix?

Comment: You could use OpenCV, which exposes some C++ methods to convert images to greyscale, but that's a very involved approach on Android...

Comment: I'm already committed to using BoofCV... Unfortunately there is no given function to do just what I need to be doing...

Comment: ColorMatrix... ColorMatrix... No need for external libraries!

Comment: I'll try using them... Do you by chance have any sources I could use? Never used them before...

Comment: Search - `android colormatrix greyscale`

Comment: As I understand it this will only transform my Bitmap to be greyscaled. However what I need in the end is a byte array containing values between 0-255 for each pixel in the image.
The problem is not that the greyscaling is taking so much time, it's the conversion between Bitmap and the byte array...

Comment: Once you have the greyscaled bitmap, convert it to a byte array.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding... What I want is a direct way to go from byte[] jpeg Data to byte[] grey data. the grey data not be RGB, just grey values (meaning 1byte) per pixel instead of 4...
If I convert it to bitmap, then to byte array with RGB (even though it's greyed it will still give me RGB values,but they will all be the same) and then dropping 1/3rd of the entries it's taking a lot of time... I need a direct way to go from jpeg to byte array... without the bitmap in between...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, the fastest way would be to just decode the Y component and ignore Cb and Cr in the stream.

Comment: How is this y component coded into the JPEG Array? Do you have any resources where I can look up? I googled around a lot and couldnt find anything...

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=VPB1FTFQG5PJH1AFZ51M